# Eventbrite API PHP, how to do sorting and display one event?

Tags: php, api, eventbrite

I am using the php library of Eventbrite API to get a list of all events from a user. The default call pulls the list as sorted in ascending order:

```
$events = $eb_client->user_list_events();
```

1. What is the correct syntax to get the list in descending order?
2. Is there a way to pull only the earliest upcoming event instead of the whole list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The default display for user_list_events is in ascending order, but you can modify this using the asc_or_desc parameter. Valid options include ‘asc’ or results in ascending order or ‘desc’ or descending order based on event start_date.
2. If you only want to display one specific event, you can use the event_get method, which uses the id of the requested event to display only that event.